# Firebase - Observing changes to document - How to know when they are from server (complete)?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been testing and reading but can't get it right.

I've read that metadata changes to documents wouldn't trigger snapshot listener events so it wouldn't be possible to check whether the document being fetched is from the cache or not. (Otherwise that would be possible through `(documentSnapshot?.metadata.isFromCache)!`).

My problem relies on the following. After the user press a button  in view controller A , I set data to a document in Firestore (I create a new document with random ID and store the ID in a variable of view controller  A) and go directly to view controller B. In view controller B, I would like to wait for the confirmation that my data is in the server.

Therefore, I query it using the ID stored in ViewController A (which I passed in `prepareForSegue:` to ViewController B) and retrieve the data for the document, specially the `status` field.

I would like to have 2 scenarios:

1) Show activity indicator. If there's no document after some amount of time like 20s, show error screen to user handle it  (Like a button to try again)

2) Show activity indicator. The document is retrieved. Stop acitivy indicator and proceed normally.

The problem is that it's always going into the second scenario, since Firebase first fetch from the local database. **How do I make sure I am only listening to changes from the server in this case?**

Comment: Which product? Firestore or Realtime Database? Why would it matter if an event comes from the server or client? Since when you write the event, you get a callback indicating when it succeeds at the server, why not simply have that in a service and pass the service between views? Then you can monitor the service for completion.

Comment: @Kato, what about the timing? When too much time has passed and I haven't yet gotten any completion?

Comment: Not sure what that means. If the client never goes online there's never any completion. Not much to be done about that case. You can still show the data locally until a connection is obtained as your writes will trigger locally for listeners.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option **includeDocumentMetadataChanges** in your query and make an if   statement using the property **hasPendingWrites** to only get data that is on the server.

Below there is an example where I only update the array of users with the data that has been written in the server.

```
 this.db.collection('users')
      .onSnapshot({ includeDocumentMetadataChanges: true }, function (doc) {
        var result = [];
        doc.docs.forEach(element => {
          if (!element.metadata.hasPendingWrites) {
            result.push(element.data())
          }
        });
        return result;
      });
```